# Win7 Host - Mouse scrolling too fast causes a page up in VirtualBox Ubuntu Guest

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, mouse, scrolling

I am running VirtualBox on a Win7 host machine and running Ubuntu 14.04 on the latest version of VirtualBox 5.0.

The problem is when I scroll down too quickly on webpages, it causes the page to scroll up, like a page up effect has occured.

The exact problem was reported here:
[VirtualBox Ticket #5672](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/5672#comment:19)

And there is a post on the same issue here:
[Mouse scrolling issue when scrolling too fast it does a PGUP](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=68702)

Any solutions or suggestions are welcome on how to fix this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my problem. Ejected the Guest additions .iso and inserted it again and this resolved the scrolling problem.